# How to style browsers default checkbox with Unform jQuery plugin using custom directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-uniform

I simply want to style an checkbox for which I am using http://uniformjs.com jquery plugin with the angularjs.

Here is the checkbox input element I want to style with the plugin:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" plugin-uniform id="inline">&nbsp;Inline editing</label>
```

Here is the cutom directive I've written for that:

```
    myApp.directive('pluginUniform', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                Layout.initUniform();
            }
        };
    });
```

Here is **Layout.initUnform()** code:

```
    var Layout = function() {

    //other stuff

            initUniform: function (els) {
                if (els) {
                    jQuery(els).each(function () {
                            if ($(this).parents(".checker").size() == 0) {
                                $(this).show();
                                $(this).uniform();
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    handleUniform();
                }
            }

    function handleUniform() {
        if (!jQuery().uniform) {
            return;
        }
        var test = $("input[type=checkbox]:not(.toggle), input[type=radio]:not(.toggle, .star)");
        if (test.size() > 0) {
            test.each(function () {
                    if ($(this).parents(".checker").size() == 0) {
                        $(this).show();
                        $(this).uniform();
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    //other stuff

    }
```

I've got `uniform.default.css` and `jquery.uniform.js` in place already.

Could somebody tell me how could I style the browsers default checkbox style to to the http://uniformjs.com jQuery plugin checkbox style in angularjs using a custom directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `els` argument when you call `Layout.initUniform()`

Since the link function of directive already exposes the element as a jQuery object when jQuery library is included before angular library in the page you don't really need your Layout function

Your `handleUnform` function has several  flaws in it.

To check existence of a plugun should do `if($.fn.pluginName)`. 
Also, if you had many elements with this directive bound to it you would be looping through all of them each time the directive runs.

Try this:

```
myApp.directive('pluginUniform', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           /* element is jQuery object*/
           if (!element.parents(".checker").length) { /* size() is deprecated */
                 element.show().uniform();                          
           }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Yep, its working now, thanks :). But its giving me this error on the console now `TypeError: undefined is not a function` for `<input type="checkbox" plugin-uniform="" id="autoopen"> ` and `<input type="checkbox" plugin-uniform="" id="inline"> `.

Comment: did you include jQuery before angular in page? that is needed to make `angular.element` use jQuery

Comment: Yes, its before the angularjs lib.

Comment: usual cause is bad path or forgetting to include file